# Tell Windows XP to Standby programmatically

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, windows-xp, standby

How can I tell Windows XP to switch to standby mode programmatically with C/C++ native code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A likely function in the Win32 API is `SetSuspendState`:

```
SetSuspendState(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE);
```

From: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373201(VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`SetSystemPowerState(TRUE, TRUE);`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373206.aspx

Comment: Seems this call has been superseded by SetSuspendState